# display box shadow above the text

Tags: css

Let's say I have a simple div with some paragraphs inside.

[image]

I want to achieve a fading effect on the bottom of the div.

[image]

---

I have tried to set up a white shadow

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 10px white;
```

but obviously this didn't work, since the `box-shadow` always appears under the text.

How can I accomplish this in pure CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate the effect with CSS only, but it's a little hackish:

http://jsfiddle.net/EaXTB/1/

I put two divs as siblings:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow"></div> 
  <div class="copy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And positioned them absolutely:

```
.container { position:relative; }

.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 10px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
  position:absolute;
}

.copy {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

The only trouble is that for this to work, you must specify the height for the `.shadow` class. If it will always be the same size, then you can use this. Otherwise using a png overlay might be more effective.

Something like:

```
.shadow {
  background: url(overlay.png) repeat-x bottom;
}
```

Comment: Do ```top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;``` on the .shadow class instead of setting the height and width. No need for z-index either.

Comment: This is bad approach. It blocks text, so you cannot select it.

Answer (score 18):

What about using the "after" css selector ? it even work with IE8 : http://caniuse.com/#search=after

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -15px; right: -15px;
    box-shadow: inset white 0 -15px 10px;
}
```

I'm using negative left and right to put the inside box outside the main box to avoid the shadow on the sides.

Comment: This is much more clean version which I also use.

Comment: "it even work with IE8" But box-shadow doesn't, so who cares ie8?! :D

Comment: That's right, so I guess you can just use the trick and use a background image positioned at the bottom of the "after" block instead of the "box-shadow".

Answer (score 3):

```
div {
    height:300px;
    color:red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0px -50px 50px -50px #000 inset;
    position:fixed;
    top: 250px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a div below all your other divs and set a negative bottom margin to that div and a top drop shadow. You can do that or you can do what I have done. Save a png image with that fade and set it to an absolutely positioned div that sits at the bottom of your relatively positioned div that contains the text.

Comment: Reminds me that a foreground-image CSS rule would come in handy.